# How to set wallpaper using system default action

Tags: android, crop, wallpaper

> I have to set the image from sdcard as wallpaper by calling the default system action..

Answer (score 0):

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "your_image.jpg");
String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
File imageFile = new File(path);

if(imageFile.exists()) {
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);

    WallpaperManager mWallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);

    try {
        mWallpaperManager.setBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Add below permission in `Menifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
```

**Code for launching cropping activity:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP", myIntent.getData());
if (myIntent.getStringExtra("mimeType") != null) {
   intent.setDataAndType(myIntent.getData(), myIntent.getStringExtra("mimeType"));
}
intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
intent.putExtra("aspectX", 1);
intent.putExtra("aspectY", 1);
intent.putExtra("outputX", 96);
intent.putExtra("outputY", 96);
intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CROP_PHOTO);
```

Comment: @karthik yes its directly set.

Comment: @ CapDroid i want crop the image by using system default action and set wallpaper..